# Trigger a javascript function from nodejs backend

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building an interactive aplication for kids. I'm working with some sensors that sends UDP data and I need to do something with that on screen.
I want to work with node js in order to receive these udp commands (that's fine for me). The problem is that I can't find the way that node trigger some function to the frontend javascript vanilla. Is there a way to do that? I know I can comunicate java with node using post and emit, but for that, java must make the request first and wait for a concrete answer, in this case, *frontend must be always waiting for node commands*.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do the same in frontend javascript. You establish a communication channel between frontend javascript and backend javascript in node. Using e.g. WebSockets or using pulling using HTTP requests.

Comment: [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to push from the server to the client if you first establish a connection using Websockets. The alternative approach is to frequently poll the server.

To use websockets, grab a library such as [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) by using `npm install ws` and basically follow their docs. Example from their docs:

```
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});
```